# Prove Proof By Cases Using Laws of Inference

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am a bit stuck proving the "proof by cases" using the basic laws of inference. Namely, I need to show that `(P -> Q), ((not P) -> Q)` implies `Q`.

How can I do that without making any leaps?

Comment: We need details about the *proof system* you are using...

Comment: @MadPhysicist  There are *many* different proof systems all with different sets of inference rules. And yes, some of these rules are 'basic' ... but the devil is in the details. So: please tell us *exactly* which rules you are allowed to use, or else we can't really help you.

Comment: That makes sense. I will make an addendum in a bit with the allowed rules of inference.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*

You have to use *Excluded Middle* : $P \lor \lnot P$ and then apply [Proof by Cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination):

$$
\cfrac{P \to Q \ \ \ \lnot P \to Q \ \ \ P \lor \lnot P}{\therefore Q}
$$

---

Another possibility is to use [Material Implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) to convert the premises into:

> $\lnot P \lor Q$ and $P \lor Q$

followed by [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#Resolution_rule):

$$
\cfrac{\lnot P \lor Q \ \ \ \ P \lor Q}{Q \lor Q}
$$

The conclusion follows by [Idempotent laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the following rules of logic:

The generalized principle of proof by n-cases:

$$[P_1 \lor P_2 \lor P_3 \lor \cdots  P_n]\land [[P_1\to Q] \land [P_2\to Q] \land \cdots [P_n \to Q]] \to Q$$

where the $P_i$ and $Q$ are any logical propositions.

The principle of the excluded middle:

$$P \lor \neg P$$

where $P$ is any logical proposition.